# AWS - Setup OIDC authentication in ALB with AWS Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, elastic-beanstalk, amazon-alb, amazon-beanstalk, oidc

I have to setup my application in elastic beanstalk with High availability. My architecture involves a php application running in beanstalk in private subnet with ALB (public subnet) which is also created as part of Beanstalk.
I want to have OIDC MYID or Azure AD authentication setup in ALB. How can I do it?

Does beanstalk ALB supports creating oidc authentication also ?
or
any other way to achieve the OIDC authentication with ALB with application running in beanstalk.